# hibernate - return insert script from a query result

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

Is there an existing library/framework that I can leverage on that will allow me to generate an `INSERT` mysql scripts from a query result.

For example, in HQL I have:

```
SELECT book FROM book b WHERE b.created >= :today
```

Instead of a `List<Book>`, what I'll have are the texts:

```
INSERT INTO book VALUES (...)
```

Or anyway I can convert list of hibernate entity into a mysql script `INSERT INTO` script.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO book (id, name, isbn) VALUES ('|| b.id ||','|| b.name ||','|| b.isbn ||');' FROM book b;
```

You need to pay attention to VARCHAR column, because the values need to be escaped with quotes.

Comment: this looks good, thanks, though it's returning null, but when I use concat() it works fine.

Comment: For null values you can use NULLIF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqldump` for this:

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname book --compact --no-create-info --where="created >= '2014-10-01'" > dump.sql
```

This will generate the `INSERT INTO` statements for table rows matching the WHERE clause `book.created >= '2014-10-01'`

Comment: I'll be needing it via java code.  And I need to not the whole database, I just want the create statements for the result of my query.

Comment: It will return only the selected rows of a single table

Comment: sorry missed that you have a where clause.  but i'll be needing it via java code where the return will be a List<String> insertStatements